# Define an object with multiple elements using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to use TypeScript for this code:

```ts
const arr = [
    {test:1,
    name:5,
    car:8
}
]
const a = arr.map((i: {test:number, car: number, name: number}) => i.test)
```

So, to define the `i` type inside `map()` function i  had to write `{test:number, car: number, name: number}`, but exists an alternative to define that `i` has Object type without defining each element from `i`?

Comment: You can just omit type and let typescript infer it `const a = arr.map((i) => i.test)` Alternatively it would also be cleaner if you used an interface

Comment: or `i:any` will take anything

Comment: You didn't need to define the type at all, TS is perfectly capable of inferring it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gKBjmBvKAU2gC4BGAGm1zDgFtCSBWK3GYREgDkwF9MAuplCRYcVPCQA6OnAAOACgUBLAJSoAfDGVSi0VZiA

Answer (score 2):

You have to define an interface

```
interface MyInterface {
    test: number,
    name:number,
    car:number
}

const arr: MyInterface[] = [
  {
    test:1,
    name:5,
    car:8
  }
];

const a = arr.map( i => i.test)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZc5SAZzAC5kQBXAWwCNoAaUihuZiWkzaduFBHCiCW7KKQC%20pBAHsQNZBMlosOWIggBtALrIAvMn2jyBanQCMXMhRB8BAVgc9xkgBzzShxRU1OFN1KCgAOmY4AAcACmRgUwA%20RIibAEogA)